Как найти слово или цифру из определенного кол-ва символов или цифр в Notepad++ или в каком то другом интрументе
Подскажите пожалуйста как в нотпад++ выделить слово или цифры состоящие из определенного кол-ва символов , вот к примеру мне нужно выделить каждое слово где имеется 14 букв или цифр(слово может быть любое но главное кол-во символов
Простыми словами мне нужно выделить все строки в которых есть число из определенного кол-ва цифр идущие подряд как единое слово или число(123456789 или словоедем) то есть что бы выделило каждую строку где есть слово или цифра состоящая из 9 символов
Буду признателен за помощь)

Поиск по регулярному выражению \b[[:alnum:]]{14}\b
Расшифровка:
\b — граница слова.
[[:alnum:]] — любой символ из набора букв и цифр
{14} — то что слева повторяется ровно 14 раз
Если внутри слова буквы и цифры не должны быть перемешаны, то искать отдельно для набора [[:alpha:]] (только буквы) и [[:digit:]] (цифры), который имеет сокращённую запись \d.
Если нужно искать или 14 цифр или 14 букв, то применяем операцию «или» |
\b([[:alpha:]]{14}|\d{14})\b
Источник: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions

Спасибо большое очень помогло!! А не подскажете можно ли как то через регулярные выражения в Emueditor делать поиск сразу по нескольких запросам ( к примеру мне надо найти "вт/, .вт, и вт." Что бы не по одному искать а сразу все 3 вышеуказанных в примере варианта,если так возможно конечно. Если в нот

Используйте символ "вертикальная черта"  для перечисления вариантов. Точку нужно экранировать (заменять на \.) если не понимаете английский по ссылке выше, начните с википедии  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F
